# How to change customized CPrintDialog's properties

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

I want to change CPrintDialog's properties when Printer change from my App.

I have set the Printer name in the OnInitDialog() of my custom CPrintDialog.

```
CComboBox *wndCmbBox = (CComboBox *)GetDlgItem( IDC_PER_USER );
if( wndCmbBox != NULL )
{
    wndCmbBox->SelectString( -1, s_PrinterName);
}
```

The problem is that, Printer name can set in the combo box but its property does not set.
I mean to say that Printer Status, type, etc...
By default, Default Printer's property set. So, its conflict.

But, if I changed the Printer from the combobox of the CPrintDialog then automatically its property changed as per the Printer selection.

I dint find any solution yet from anywhere. Please refer the image I have attached.

[image: CPrintDialog]

**Edit**
As cody suggest, I can changed the Printer as per selected printer from my App, Even If I apply Print command, then print goes from the selected printer, this all gone well,
But this is not the issue, The issue is, on first time of open Print dialog, its properties does not match to the selected printer, if the printer is selected other then Default printer from my App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have resolved my Printer proprieties's issue.

I have put this code after initializing the `m_pd` structure before `doModal()`.

```
HGLOBAL hDevMode = NULL;
HGLOBAL hDevNames = NULL;
if (GetPrinterDevice( CurrentPrinterName.GetBuffer(), &hDevNames, &hDevMode))
{
    AfxGetApp()->SelectPrinter(hDevNames, hDevMode);

}
```

I have pass the `hDevMode` and `hDevNames` in the `GetPrinterDevice()` function.

Its working fine without any side effect.

Still warm thanks to `@Cody Gray` and `@roger_rowland` for their support..:)

Answer (score 8):

You are doing it wrong. You should *not* customize printing settings by displaying the printer dialog and programmatically manipulating its controls. That's bound to go wrong, just like you've observed it does. This is not the expected use model for a common dialog.

Instead, set default values for the `CPrintDialog` by modifying its `m_pd` structure, as described in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk61115a.aspx):

> To use a `CPrintDialog` object, first create the object using the `CPrintDialog` constructor. Once the dialog box has been constructed, you can set or modify any values in the `m_pd` structure to initialize the values of the dialog box's controls. The `m_pd` structure is of type [`PRINTDLG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646843.aspx). For more information on this structure, see the Windows SDK.

You can also programmatically change the default printer for your entire application. This doesn't require showing any dialogs at all. To do this, call the [`SelectPrinter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5fkxh8d.aspx) function. This sets a new printer and releases the previously-selected printer.

Once you've done this, any time the print dialog is displayed, it will automatically show the specified printer as selected. And when you retrieve information about the selected printer, the information you will retrieve will apply to the correct printer.

Find more information in this MSDN article: [How to programmatically print to a non-default printer in MFC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/166129)

Comment: Hey Buddy, I tried all the above way that you suggest, but still my issue is not resolved.. Need some more help..

Comment: What exactly did you try? What went wrong? You haven't updated the question with any more code, and I'm sitting too far away to see your computer screen.

Comment: @AB Bolim - to be honest, it seems to me that Cody told you everything you need to know in answer to your question. IMHO you should do the honourable thing and accept it.

Comment: @roger_rowland - Hey man, Whatever Cody suggest that I already tried, but I dint work on the first time When the Printer changed from my app other then default and the Printer Dialog open, It show me the changed printer whichever I changed from my app, but its properties does not changed, as given in the Screen shot. Its display the default printer properties. But, after that if I changed printer from my Printer dialog, then all gone well. And please, I am honestly saying, cause I dont care about this bounty and all. But still you guys fill that you are right then I can accept your answer.

Comment: Ok I see you have a point, but even so, you'll not get a better answer, in my opinion .... but it's your choice anyway ... no sweat :-)

Comment: You may right `@roger_rowland`, `Cody Gray` try to explain everything that he knows in a best way I think but still above answer dint solve my issue, then how can I mark it as my ans. Even I am also trying to solve this issue, and if I got anything, then I ll share it..